# Error when calling to code that creates a JButton (not visible)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have created a hangman game and would like to add a `JFrame` around it. I started with making the main screen but I am having a issue making a start `JButton`. For some reason it doesn't appear at all and I have tried multiple solutions.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainScreen extends JFrame {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");


  public mainScreen() {
   JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Screen");
  mainFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Java Projects/hangman_image.jpg")));
   mainFrame.setSize(1920, 1080);
   mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
   mainPanel = new JPanel();
   startButton = new JButton("Start");
   mainPanel.add(startButton);

   mainFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

The frame appears but not the button itself (I have tried getting rid of the image to see if it was covering it).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Note that my answer includes an MCVE. Ready to copy/paste, compile and run.) 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: .. 4) One way to get image(s) for an example (mentioned in point (1)) is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 5) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: When you `mainFrame.add` you add using the default layout manager which is `BorderLayout`.  In fact `mainFrame.add(new JLabel(..))` is equivalent to `mainFrame.add(new JLabel(..), BorderLayout.CENTER)` which is the default. By doing `mainFrame.add` twice, you add two components to `BorderLayout` center, which can take only one.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `mainPanel` was not added to a visible container. See further tips in code comments.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// no need to extend JFrame ..
//public class mainScreen extends JFrame {
public class mainScreen {

    // this is never addded to a visible container so .. (1)
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");

    public mainScreen() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Screen");
        mainFrame.add(new JLabel("C:/../hangman_image.jpg"));
        // (1) .. add it!
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        // don't guess.. 
        //mainFrame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        // .. instead
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // it is already instantiated, no need to do it twice! 
        //mainPanel = new JPanel();
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        mainPanel.add(startButton);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            mainScreen ms = new mainScreen();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the panel but you are not adding it to mainframe even though your button has been added in panel.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Test1 extends JFrame {
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");


public Test1() {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Screen");
    mainFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/filelocation")));
    mainFrame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    startButton = new JButton("Start");
    mainPanel.add(startButton);
    //here you add your panel to mainFrame
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

}


public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test1();
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first import does not exist (compilation problem) and the rest besides `swing` are unused. More importantly, the `JLabel` is covered by the addition of the `mainPanel`. This is a common problem with adding two components (without constraints) to a `BorderLayout`.

Comment: You are right, removed unused import, and question was that why the button does not appear so my focus was to highlight the root cause why it was not happening.  Thank you

Comment: Try changing `new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/filelocation"))` to `new JLabel("/filelocation")`. Do you 'see' the problem?

Comment: Your label will be floated, but that is not the root cause here of not showing up the `button` to my understanding.